# How to create class instances from a list?

Tags: python, list, class, object, instance

I am new to this site and new to coding so please forgive me.

I have been practicing coding and was wondering if anyone can help.

Say I have a `class exampleClass`.

Instead of doing:

```
x = exampleClass()
y = exampleClass()
z = exampleClass()
```

Can I just specify:

```
list = ['x','y','z']
```

then create the class instances?

I have searched and tried several code exampled but was not able to do it.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754180/create-multiple-instances-of-a-class#18755477 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405282/many-instances-of-a-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405282/many-instances-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to map class instances to specific values:

```
>>> class Example:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ExampleObject'


>>> {k: Example() for k in ('x', 'y', 'z')}
{'z': ExampleObject, 'y': ExampleObject, 'x': ExampleObject}
```

Although possible, you generally want to avoid creating variable names dynamically, and use a container instead such as a list - if you need to access you values by index - or dictionary - if you need to access your values by a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no neat way to create variables by name. One alternative option might be to create a list with a given number of instances of `exampleClass` using a list comprehension:

```
[exampleClass() for _ in range(3)]
```

which can then be unpacked into variables:

```
x, y, z = [exampleClass() for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about iterable unpacking. This is probably the better way to go. +1

Comment: How do I scale this for, say, 20 variables?

Comment: @Icee: Bump `3` to `20` and unpack to more variables. Having 20 variables of the same type is a sign that you might want to be using some other approach instead, though. Maybe a list?